# SnowFlake Vs. GCP (Big Query) as DWH

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-analytics, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the process of choosing a DWH for a small start up that has very small data, but that will hopefully grow to medium size data (I doubt we would reach "big data" size).

Currently, we will need connections to import from Hubspot and Google Analytics.

I have researched the differences between Snowflake and GCP Big Query, but now I am looking for validation :) Which would you choose and why?

Also, I have a few questions:

1. Can I import the nested Google Analytics data and then handle/flatten in Snowflake easily?
2. Which tool would be more cost effective in the case that I have stated?

Comment: Can you specify what is "medium" data and "small" data? Why go to a "DWH" solution if it's not needed?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @TomSlabbaert. Small means a few tables with not too much data - maybe 10s of thousands of rows. Medium - eventually we will hit 100s of thousands and potentially more than a million.

But, there is only one production DB and then we will integrate with other data sources such as Hubspot and GA. Everything should be in one place for normalization and cleaning

Answer (score 2):

Both are excellent services. I would select one primarily based on the team's skillsets and/or available people to hire.

BigQuery has a very large developer market, but Snowflake is also doing well. People generally are a lot more expensive than the services they manage (you mention small to medium datasets).

Regarding pricing, you must analyze your data and then complete a cost analysis. I always analyze costs, but I seldom make pricing a decision point. There are many factors to consider beyond the pricing of a service. Review fixed monthly costs, variable fees, and possibly most important, the cost and availability of support.

Google Analytics is well structured, so either service can probably do way more than you require.

You could probably flip a coin and not make a terrible choice.

Comment: I totally agree with that answer. IMO, I hate the infrastructure and I prefer the managed/serverless product. In addition BigQuery is very well integrated with the Google Cloud ecosystem (and you can go easily to the next level!). Snowflake has the main advantage to be Cloud agnostic and to reuse your skills/assets anywhere.

Comment: Support for ICEBERG would alter my vote. Snowflake has ICEBERG support in private preview -> however I've not met a single person with access to any Snowflake Private Previews.